# SQL left join and group_concat returns duplicate data

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, group-concat

I am trying to return data from 3 different tables with 2 left joins. All tables return multiple rows.
Here is my statement:

```
SELECT s.*, GROUP_CONCAT(sp.photo) AS photos, GROUP_CONCAT(st.name) AS tags
FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN sites_photos sp
ON sp.sites_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN sites_tags st
ON st.sites_id = s.id
WHERE s.id = 30
```

The data this statement returns looks like:

```
Array
(
[id] => 30
[url] => www.test.be
[name] => test
[date] => 2014-08-16
[photos] => 201408141132191_gummies.jpg, 201408141132191_gummies.jpg, 201408141132191_gummies.jpg, 201408141132191_gummies.jpg, 201408141132191_gummies.jpg, 201408141132191_gummies.jpg, 201408141132191_gummies.jpg, 201408141132194_gummies.jpg, 201408141132194_gummies.jpg, 201408141132194_gummies.jpg, 201408141132194_gummies.jpg, 201408141132194_gummies.jpg, 201408141132194_gummies.jpg, 201408141132194_gummies.jpg
[tags] => test, hello, ale, print, social, more, hcp, test, hello, ale, print, social, more, hcp
)
```

Like you can see "tags" are returned twice and the "photos" more than 5 times. When I remove one LEFT JOIN the query returns the right data. How can prevent the statement from returning duplicate data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sp.photo) AS photos, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT st.name)
```

Comment: Perfect! What does the DISTINCT do exactly?

Comment: It will select distinct values.

Comment: Translated it ;) Only unique values will be selected. Thanks for your help.